# "cannot create an instance from the abstract class" with grails plugin

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, liquibase

When trying to start a project (`./grailsw run-app`) for the first time with the [latest version](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) of the database-migration plugin, it fails with the following error:

```
Error Compilation error: startup failed:
[..]/work/plugins/database-migration-1.3.8/src/groovy/grails/plugin/databasemigration/GormDatabaseSnapshotGenerator.groovy: 48: You cannot create an instance from the abstract class 'liquibase.snapshot.DatabaseSnapshot'.
 @ line 48, column 31.
    DatabaseSnapshot snapshot = new DatabaseSnapshot(db, requestedSchema)
```

I'm using java7 on OSX:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
```

This seems vaguely familiar to me; I was able to find [random](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.groovy.user/44112) [references](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-3443) to other projects in 2009-2011 about this. Nothing current; and [nothing found in the specific plugin's issue tracker](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPDATABASEMIGRATION#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Asummary-panel). I'd ask there but I expect this is a fairly standard issue, not related to the specific grails plugin.

A peer is using java6. I went back to java6 (apple(tm) version), ran `./gradlew --refresh-dependencies run-app` and got the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [liquibase made that class abstract](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/commit/42a857e59074145f1df528338ddadb5e733e05f8#diff-07d50b9da527d871d17df372707951a3R41) in v3

However, the plugin looks like it should be using v2.0.5

So as far as I can see, [for v2.0.5 it *should* be ok](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/d93e6a8b4a6debae14b356e6ea9d18686eb127e7/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/snapshot/DatabaseSnapshot.java)?

Unless you've added a dependency to liquibase v3?

Comment: I think it's using [2.0.3](https://github.com/burtbeckwith/grails-database-migration/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy), not 2.0.5. That should still be ok though.

Comment: @Didericis Ahhh, I was going [from this](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration/blob/master/grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy)

Comment: I see liquibase 2.0.5 in ~/.m2, confirmed with grailsw dependency-report. And I don't have any explicit configuration of liquibase in my BuildConfig.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I guess you're pulling from the source @tim_yates linked to after all, or something similar. I think you're going to have to dig back through a bunch of dependencies and find out if any are calling for liquibase v3.

Comment: Yeah, the [javadoc for 2.0.5](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/2.0.5/liquibase-core-2.0.5-javadoc.jar/!/liquibase/snapshot/DatabaseSnapshot.html) and [the source](https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/repositories/releases/archive/org/liquibase/liquibase-core/2.0.5/liquibase-core-2.0.5-sources.jar/!/liquibase/snapshot/DatabaseSnapshot.java) shows it's not `abstract`.